# Gallery slideshow won't appear on wordpress

Tags: wordpress, gallery, slideshow

I'm using wordpress.com, and I have an issue with the slideshow gallery. It will appear on it's own page, with nothing else there, but will not when put into a `div` column on a separate page. Essentially, this appears normally as a slideshow:

`[gallery type="slideshow" ids="92,91,90,89,85,86,87,88,84,83,82,81,77,78,80,76,75,74"]`

but this only shows the thumbnail version of the gallery:

```
<div style="float: right; width: 40%; overflow: auto; height: 450px;">
  [gallery type="slideshow" ids="92,91,90,89,85,86,87,88,84,83,82,81,77,78,80,76,75,74"]
</div>
```

I'm wondering, how can I have the slideshow appear when it is in the `div` column?
Thanks for any and all help!

Answer (score 0):

Second example shows the version of the gallery with `width:40%` as set in the style attribute, and adjusts the size of pictures accordingly. Gallery is by default wrapped inside `div` and has default `classes` that are based on shortcode options:

`.gallery`
`.galleryid-{$id}`
`.gallery-columns-{$columns}`
`.gallery-columns-{$size}`

Overriding the styles in default classes and using the shortcode options is enough to do most of customization. I recommend that you check the [Gallery Shortcode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Gallery_Shortcode) documentation, how to modify an existing theme with a [Child Theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes), and how to use browser development tool like [Firebug](http://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/customizing-your-wordpress-theme-using-firebug/) ( I hope you won't be offended if you already know this ).